# Mobile phone web app related questions allowed?

Tags: discussion, scope

Is it appropriate to ask a question about a web app related to a specific mobile device?

Example:

When browsing X on my device Y, I have problem Z, what do I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think we *can* say no to these if we want the site to be successful. One thing is for sure - mobile Internet usage is getting more & more significant.

This is really no different from saying "I'm on a PC using Chrome" vs "I'm on a Mac using Firefox"... why not allow "I'm on Windows Mobile using IE" or "I'm on an iPhone using Safari" or whatever? Otherwise do we rule out netbooks with Google Chrome OS? What about iPads? What about other tablet PCs?

I think we have to accept them on the same basis that we do for all questions - that we're trying to answer a question that revolves mainly around the functionality of the site, not the application used to access that site.

Comment: yes, as long as the focus of the question is the *website* and not the device/browser used to access it.

Comment: @x3ja, Is this still the current policy? How does this match up with http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/q/2504/10579

Comment: A web app used on a smartphone is okay, but a question about a native app isn't. A question about the Gmail app is off-topic. A question about using the mobile version of the Gmail web app is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to say no, since it normally has nothing to do with the web app, but with the smartphone.

Which is why we need the electronic gadgets site to launch too!

Comment: Are you saying such questions are on-topic in http://android.stackexchange.com / http://apple.stackexchange.com ?